# Why is Mocha not working with Yarn Berry?

Tags: mocha.js, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I'm trying to do a very simple test using mocha (no config files, no additional flags, just `mocha`, `yarn2`, and `testee.js` file), but it always give me `0 passing`. Hell, it won't even run any file!

```js
// testee.js

console.log('test') // No output

describe('something', () => {
    it('Should run', () => {
        console.log('test 2') // No output either
    })
})
```

```sh
$ yarn mocha testee.js

  0 passing (1ms)
```

Tools I'm using:

- Mocha 9.0.2
- Yarn Berry 2.4.2

Is mocha unsupported by Yarn 2? Should I use something else? I always use mocha for all of my test files, maybe it's time to migrate if that really is the case.

Note: I tried using yarn 1 and it worked flawlessly. Also, Mocha found the `testee.js` file, otherwise it would give me `not found` error instead of `0 passing`

Comment: If a bug you should open an issue on our repository (Yarn). However, Mocha is covered by an E2E test and a bug seems unlikely (https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/master/.github/workflows/e2e-mocha-workflow.yml#L31-L47).

Answer (score 1):

Mocha 9 uses ESM-first approach to imports
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/releases/tag/v9.0.0

Yarn 2+ with the default PnP install scheme does not support ESM yet, because Node API lacks some features to make this possible

For the time being, if you want to use Mocha 9, you have to use `node_modules` install scheme with Yarn 2+ by changing your config to:
`.yarnrc.yml`

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
...
```

and running `yarn` to reinstall your project with `node_modules`

You can track ESM support for Yarn PnP here:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/638